# UK Skilled Worker Dependent Visa - Questions

Tags: united-kingdom

I am in the UK on a SWV, my fiancé is in the UAE and we are Pakistani by passport. We are planning to get married in Pakistan and she is returning to the UAE for work and applying for a dependant visa. I have some questions regarding the following sections:

> For either the UK or any other country, have you ever been: Refused a visa, Refused entry at the border, Refused permission to stay or remain?

1. She was laid off from her job in August, so she returned to Pakistan and came back to the UAE on another job offer. Does this count as "Refused permission to stay or remain?" When she got laid off, her visa got canceled, so she could no longer stay in the UAE. It's kind of a gray area.

---

> Have you been to any other countries in the past 10 years?

2. The time when she got laid off, she exited the country (UAE). Does that need to be a part of this section?

---

3. Accommodation proof

I have filled out the application form in advance. My Proof of accommodation is not asked for in the mandatory documents, should I still attach it?

---

4. Third-party declaration

Do I need to sign the third-party declaration (at the end of the application) as her husband on behalf of her application? Or can she say that she is representing herself? I will be attaching my bank statements for proof as well. The exact option shown in the application is: "I am submitting the form on behalf of the applicant."

Answer (score 3):

1. No. Even though her visa may have been 'cancelled', the question is only referring to if she *applied* to remain and was specifically refused. Not if her leave was curtailed due to the conditions of an existing visa.
2. Yes.
3. If you've got it, attach it. It can't hurt. If the case worker is not interested (or finds it irrelevant) they'll just set it aside. That said, do try to avoid clutter. It just stresses them out. That single bit extra shouldn't be a problem.
4. The third party declaration is for an immigration lawyer (or other such licensed legal represetative) if she chooses one to represent her and file the application on her behalf. If she is filing on her own behalf then *she* is the main applicant an there is no third party declaration.